# GIT create pull request with branches with different histories

Tags: git, github

I have master branch. for some time it already had some commits. Then I have created develop branch from it. After some time, I want to merge it back to master, but squash it so it has only one commit (currently there are many of them.

Out of the develop I created a branch, e.g. develop-fix-branch.

Then I deleted the develop.
Then I have created empty develop with these commands:

```
git checkout --orphan develop
git rm -rf .
git commit --allow-empty -m "root commit"
git push origin develop
```

That created an empty branch named develop. All good.

Now I planned to create a PR from develop-fix-branch --> develop and squash all commits, in hopes I will have develop with only one commit, I am getting this message:

> There isn’t anything to compare.  develop and develop-fix-branch are
>   entirely different commit histories.

What can I do to have develop again with only one commit, and later also merge it back to master, having also one commit as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was overcomplicating.

I have simply removed the .git file and did the following:

```
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repo
git add *
git commit -am 'message'
git push -f origin master
```

Now I have master with only one commit.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a somewhat complicated way of achieving something else. And it does not sound entirely right, there are essentially two commonly used methods of squashing your history. You can perform an interactive `rebase` and use `squash` or `fixup` (former will prompt you to edit the commit messages of resulting squashed commit).

Let's assume your changes are on top of current `master` (e.g. you've rebased; if not, you can use for instance `git merge-base --fork-point master` to learn what `ref` you should base your interactive rebase to):

```
git rebease -i master
```

The other option (I personally for multiple reasons prefer the above one), is to `reset` your branches reflog (soft reset) to the `ref` on which you want to have a single commit (e.g. `master` from the above example).

```
git reset master
git add .  # or -u or whatever makes sure correct changes are staged
git commit
```

And you can `push` that.